# Hightchart: Invalid argument line 83 in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, gwt-highcharts

I am using Highcharts JS v3.0.1 to draw a chart in one of page. The chart is working in FF, Chrome and IE9 even Saferi but not in IE8.

I am getting the below error

*Invalid argument. 
highcharts.js, line 83 character 1*

In line 86 I have the below code

```
z.createStyleSheet().cssText="hcv\\:fill, hcv\\:path, hcv\\:shape, hcv\\:stroke{ behavior:url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; } "},isHidden:function(){return!this.box.offsetWidth},clipRect:function(a,b,c,d){var e=this.createElement(),f=V(a);return v(e,{members:[],left:f?a.x:a,top:f?a.y:b,width:f?a.width:c,height:f?a.height:d,getCSS:function(a){var b=a.element,c=b.nodeName,a=a.inverted,d=this.top-(c==="shape"?b.offsetTop:0),e=this.left,b=e+this.width,f=d+this.height,d={clip:"rect("+t(a?e:d)+
```

Is it knowing issue in IE8?

can the above error be fixed in IE8? If this issue can be fixed in IE8, Please tell what could be the issue and how it can be resolved.

Could you please guide me on this?

Thanks

Comment: You should expand the text, or import the non-minified version of highcharts.  That line of text included is incomprehensible.

Comment: This is SVG related yes? IE8 does not support SVG.